# How can i save the Kafka read Structured Streaming data as a Dataframe and apply parsing on it?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read realtime streaming data from Kafka topics through Spark Structured streaming, However my understanding i would need the streaming to stop at sometime so i can apply my parsing logic on it and push it to MongoDB. Is there a way i can save the streaming data into a separate dataframe with/without stopping the streaming?

I checked the guide and other blogs and i am not getting a straight forward answer for my requirement

```
val df = spark
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:9092, host:9092, host:9092")
.option("subscribe", "TOPIC_P2_R2, TOPIC_WITH_COMP_P2_R2.DIT, TOPIC_WITHOUT_COMP_P2_R2.DIT")
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.load()

val dfs = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

val consoleOutput = dfs.writeStream
.outputMode("append")
.format("console")
.start()
consoleOutput.awaitTermination()
consoleOutput.stop()
```

I need the streaming data to be saved somehow in a dataframe either by stopping the streaming or without stopping

Below is the parsing logic what i have and instead of picking dataset from a file path i need the streamed data to be my new dataset and should be able to apply my rest of the logic and get output. Saving it to Mongo is not my primary focus now;

```
val log = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("C:\\Users\\raheem_mohammed\\IdeaProjects\\diag.csv")
log.createOrReplaceTempView("logs")
val df = spark.sql("select _raw, _time from logs").toDF

//Adds Id number to each of the event
val logs = dfs.withColumn("Id", monotonicallyIncreasingId()+1)
//Register Dataframe as a temp table
logs.createOrReplaceTempView("logs")

val  = spark.sql("select Id, value from logs")


//Extracts columns from _raw column. Also finds the probabilities of compositeNames.
//If true then the compositeName belongs to one of the four possibilities
val extractedDF = dfss.withColumn("managed_server", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",2))
  .withColumn("alert_summary", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",3))
  .withColumn("oracle_details", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",5))
  .withColumn("ecid", regexp_extract($"_raw", "(?<=ecid: )(.*?)(?=,)",1))
  //.withColumn("CompName",regexp_extract($"_raw",""".*(composite_name|compositename|composites|componentDN):\s+(\S+)\]""",2))
  .withColumn("CompName",regexp_extract($"_raw",""".*(composite_name|compositename|composites|componentDN):\s+([a-zA-Z]+)""",2))
  .withColumn("composite_name", col("_raw").contains("composite_name"))
  .withColumn("compositename", col("_raw").contains("compositename"))
  .withColumn("composites", col("_raw").contains("composites"))
  .withColumn("componentDN", col("_raw").contains("componentDN"))

//Filters out any NULL values if found
val finalData = extractedDF.filter(
  col("managed_server").isNotNull &&
    col("alert_summary").isNotNull &&
    col("oracle_details").isNotNull &&
    col("ecid").isNotNull &&
    col("CompName").isNotNull &&
    col("composite_name").isNotNull &&
    col("compositename").isNotNull &&
    col("composites").isNotNull &&
    col("componentDN").isNotNull)

    finalData.show(false)
```

Comment: `dfs` here is already a DataFrame. You can call DataFrame's method such as `map` to parse the data. Did I miss anything?

Comment: So i can use the dfs in my case to parse my logic and i dont need to use consoleOutput as it only displays the streaming data on my shell. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: when i do dfs.show() i get org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start(). This is the reason i wrote  
val consoleOutput = dfs.writeStream
.outputMode("append")
.format("console")
.start()
consoleOutput.awaitTermination()
consoleOutput.stop()

Comment: Please check the official MongoDB connector example here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/examples/src/test/scala/tour/SparkStructuredStreams.scala

Comment: I edit my question adding my logic so you people can better understand what my requirement is. Any suggestions will be of great help

Comment: @RaheemMohammad you can't run show() on a streaming dataframe. if you need to do some parsing on your streaming dataframe you can use map/flatmap or sql queries. if you need to display the data for debugging on a small set of data you can either use print in the map function (running locally) or using the "memory" writer and then read from the saved table. keep in mind that in streaming applications you have an infinite stream of data so it doesn't make sense to print/write to log your data in production.